# Moto G7 Power (XT1955-4) detects two touch inputs

Tags: touch

I bought an aftermarket replacement LCD + touch for my Moto G7 Power off [Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/snapshot/0.html?spm=a2g0o.9042647.6.2.7cae4c4djmfjIB&orderId=8143521276004854&productId=1005002333723440). However, it has an issue.

The problem is that it sometimes detects a touch in the top middle of the screen. This is the part of the screen where the notch is. So an actual physical touch on that part of the screen could never be registered because there is no touch sensing there.

When I then touch the screen anywhere else with just one finger, it detects two touch inputs. My screen is unusable in this state (obviously). I have to turn the screen off and back on again to get rid of this error. Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

I have tried cleaning the connector, wiping data and cache + Dalvik cache. I downgraded my phone to another firmware version. I tried two different custom ROMs (LineageOS 18 and 17) but the issue persists. I'm using the original charging cable. No screen protector. It happens during normal usage without the phone heating up bad. A restart doesn't help, it only temporarily fixes the issue in the same way turning the screen off and on again does. Sometimes it happens 1 minute after I turn the screen on, sometimes it doesn't happen for half an hour. On average I would say it happens 50 times a day, which is getting very annoying.

I managed to start the partial screen app and press *RUN SCREEN ANALYSIS* through ADB shell after the glitch started happening. But after a minute, the app tells me "no areas were added". The erroneous touch is happening at (339.5; 0) so I also tried starting the analysis and then sending a tap event at those coordinates but still, no areas were added.

Is there anything I can do? Like making the system permanently ignore touch inputs in that region? I'm fine with such a solution as long as it works. I have some knowledge about Unix and Android systems, but I'm not an expert at this. Btw, I have already filed a complaint with the seller.

[EDIT]:
I managed to remove the notch by installing *None Display Cutout* through Magisk. This allowed me to run *partial screen* full screen. Then I did an analysis in partial screen and sent an input event through ADB with: `adb shell input tap 339.5 0`. This time, a partial screen found an area and has included it in its ignored regions. However, the glitch keeps happening still!